# SQL Server export images to network drives

Tags: sql-server, permissions

We have an app which sends images to a SQL server table. I set up a DSN with a certain user and set this user in SQL logins to have permission to do so.
This works without any problem.

The images are exported by the table trigger as images to a LOCAL drive. This works as well.

What does NOT work is the export to a NETWORK drive or another local partition.

Does this require any sql permissions or permission for that user for export??
If so, why is this neccessary, because whenever the image date is in the table the user shouldn't be relevant in my understanding.

Please help in this issue.
Michael

Comment: If SQL Server is "exporting" to a network location, then the SQL Server service account needs access to that location. *Side note, exporting an image in a `TRIGGER` sounds like a bad idea. Triggers should be minimal, and saving something to disk can have quite an overhead. Also, should the save fail, for any reason, so too will the DML statement; meaning your `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` statement will be rolled back. If you need to do the event on a DML statement, you'd be better off putting the information into another table, and having a regular task do the work (or not do it in SQL at all).*

Comment: Thanks. Images are only about 500 KB max. Your remark to export to another table and then export is a good input. I will do so. But as this is a AFTER_INSERT trigger I wouldn't get any impact on the stored data I think.

Comment: Stupid question: what or which is the SQL Server service accounts is neccessary for writing to a net drive??

Comment: Find your SQL Server instance in Services. You will see the account in column "Log on As"

Comment: You (well the DBA) define the service account SQL Server runs under and the Network Administrator (with your/the DBA's input) defines what permissions it has on the network and it's shares. That isn't for the users here to tell you, and it's always specific to the workplace./

Answer (score 0):

> Does this require any sql permissions or permission for that user for
>   export??

It is not related to "sql server/instance" permissions i.e sql permissions within sql server, to server&db securables etc. It is related to the permissions of the "process" which attempts to write to the destination directory/folder.

1. if your "certain user" connects/authenticates to sql server with windows authentication (domain\certainuser) then the sql server service carries/passes through the "domain security token" of certainuser and writes the files in the directory as if certainuser was writing to that directory (assuming the directory resides in the same domain or in another trusted domain). In this case, if domain\certainuser does not have sufficient permissions to the directory, writing will fail with access denied.

2.if your "certain user" connects to sql server with sql authentication (username&password) then "certain user" does not have any "existence" outside sql server. When the sql user(==certain user) tries to access and external resource (eg. write to a directory) then the service account of the sql server instance comes at play and any mapped credentials to the "certain user" sql login.

a. if the service account of the sql server instance is a domain account (eg. domain\sqlsrvc) then this domain account needs to have sufficient permissions to the external resource/directory.

b. if the service account of the sql server instance is a windows account of the local "machine (the sql instance is running on)" then (assuming the local machine account can escape the realm of the local machine and access the network/domain) the NetworkService account of the machine needs access to the external resources/directory. The networkservice account of the machine is machinename$ (eg. if the machine/computer name is PC123, then the networkservice account is PC123$). Giving permissions for domain resources to a machine$ account is a bad security practice and most systemadmins will oppose to that.

c. if you dont want to bother with service accounts, you could create a sql server credential and map the credential to the sql login certainuser

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL sqlusertodomaincredential WITH IDENTITY = 'domain\acountX', SECRET = 'domain-password-of-accountX';
GO
ALTER LOGIN certainuser WITH CREDENTIAL = sqlusertodomaincredential;
GO
```

Sum-up:

a.Use a domain account (domain\certainuser) to connect to sql server and write to a directory.

b.If you cannot do that, create a credential for a domain account and map that to the sql login.

c.if you cannot do that, use a domain account as sql server service account.

d.if you cannot do any of the above, talk to your admins and whether it is allowed to give permissions to the machine$ networkservice account for the external resources.

Comment: Thanks. As we have case 2. we pass this on to our Admin because we need to setup as described.